# REST API w OAuth - what's the best practice to verify that the user sending a request owns the target resource?

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth, slim

We have an API with endpoints for things like user profile information where we want to restrict access.

Our application backend is built in PHP on the Slim framework so we're handling authorization in routing middleware:

```
class Authorization {
    public function authorizeAccess() {
        ... // check if oauth token corresponds to the correct id
    }
}

$authorizer = new Authorization(); 

$app->get('/user/:id/profile', [$authorizer, 'authorizeAccess'], function() use ($app) {
    ...
};
```

Is this a good way of doing this?

Comment: Which app supposed to have access to this API? A Front end js? A different server?

Comment: @batz There is a web app that already uses it as well as two mobile apps that are coming that will be hitting these endpionts

Comment: Not sure if there a special way to it in Slim framework, but in general you could limit per ip/device per day/second